# Open source, web-based math editor

Tags: editor, tex

I'm looking for an open source library of a math equation editor. I want to embed this math editor in my website. I want to have a text box (a textarea) that gives the ability to the user to insert math equations with a list of math symbols buttons. Preferably, 
the output does not have to be visually equivalent to LaTeX nor real time because I want to save all the input of the user and output it as a pdf document.
If anyone can guide me to such a open source program I would be grateful.

Comment: This might be of interest: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/5146/what-are-the-open-source-wysiwyg-independent-web-equation-editors-available-on-l. It recommends "MathQuill"

Comment: Also, there's a [list of them on Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Formula_editor).

Answer (score 1):

http://www.codecogs.com/eqneditor works pretty well for me, and is embedable.